# Issue with jQuery data() treating string as number

Tags: javascript, jquery, floating-point

I have a MySQL BIGINT that I am storing in HTML5 data. Then I'm trying to access that value and pass it through an AJAX call.

```
<div data-id="211285677671858177">
```

And the JavaScript:

```
var send_data = {
    id: '' + $(this).data('id')
}
$.post('/send.php', send_data);
```

The issue is that the jQuery `data` function seems to retrieve that value as a floating point and not a string. So appending it to a blank string isn't helping because it's already too late - it's already been rounded (in this case to `211285677671858180`). What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

This isn't a case of "long int" really, the number you're getting is the closest available representation as a floating-point number.

Anyway, you want the value as a string. Quote the [jQuery docs for `.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) (emphasis mine):

> Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value
>   (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null) otherwise
>   it is left as a string. **To retrieve the value's attribute as a string
>   without any attempt to convert it, use the attr() method.**

Comment: Okay thanks for the explanation. I wish there were a way to tell `data` not to convert it but I guess `attr` will do for now

Comment: I have also found that using the [HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) is also quite straightforward and fast to implement.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing as a "long integer" in JavaScript. All numbers are 64-bit floating point. Your number there cannot be represented exactly in IEEE-794 floating point representation.

The only way to "fix" this is to make the number into a string in a domain that can cope with big integer values.

Comment: Okay. Regardless, I don't *want* it to be a number. I want it to be treated is a string, but `data` seems to treat it as a floating point. Any ideas?

Comment: All attribute values are strings. However, jQuery tries to be helpful and converts things to numeric type when you use the `.data()` API. Try just getting the `.attr()` value of the attribute.

Answer (score 2):

try typecasting it to string:

```
id: '' + $(this).data('id').toString();
```

Comment: @andrewtweber total shot in the dark but does using $(this).attr('data-id'); keep it as a string?

Comment: Yes, that does work. Interesting... I wonder if the `data` thing is a bug then? I'll leave the question open for a while to see what others have to say

Comment: @andrewtweber it's not a bug, like others have mentioned jQuery is trying to be proactive and assumes what you most likely want. In this case it was wrong to assume.

Comment: This won't work accurately if the value starts with 0, e.g. "001".  This expression will return string "1".

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding the data attribute value in single quotes, if you want `data` to treat it like a string. Problem there, I guess, is you'll have the quotes to strip.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where the data id (alphanumeric) was getting converted through usage of .data() as a result the last few characters were getting converted to all zeroes. It took some research to determine that this is a bug in jQuery implementation of .data().

Reference: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7579

For me, to get the data id directly as a work around, I used .attr("data-id") directly and this gave me the correct id.