# Strange scientific notation behavior in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, scientific-notation

I stumbled upon some strange behaviour of auto-magically parsed numbers in javascript.

I have some product objects to show in a tabs component (of jquery UI) and these objects are only temporary so I prepared for every one of them some unique ID. I generate them so they look like this: `540718791327b`

The thing is my script which used them to identify on which tab I actually work at the moment stopped working at some point. I didn't know what happened until I did some debugging. I noticed that the uid I had in source like this: `5407153722e09` was being read by javascript as a number: `5407153722000000000`. It seems javascript treated my number as a scientific notation.

Unfortunately I wasn't able to reproduce it with jsfiddle, but here it is so you get an idea what am I doing: http://jsfiddle.net/7a3952qt/

Generally at my PC the `console.log(uid)` returns 5407153722000000000 instead of 5407153722e09. (on my webpage, on jsfiddle it works fine)

Maybe someone has any idea what might be going on? What can be the cause of behaviour like this?

Comment: Try [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/7a3952qt/1/). Does it yield `number` for you? For me, it logs `string`. Are you using a different version of jQuery than in the fiddle?

Comment: Its working fine for me, try out removing the other external js file which you have added in your project and try. This might conclude where can actually be the issue

Comment: Bergi, you'r brilliant, I switched to my version of jQuery (1.7.2) and it seems it shows `number` now. Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bfhqofty/1/ What do you suggest to do?

Comment: What about http://jsfiddle.net/bfhqofty/2/ ?

Comment: Still the same Thomas Junk, it seems the conversion happens at this point: `$(this).data('uid')`

Comment: According to this, http://stackoverflow.com/a/10958094/1981678 you might want to try using the attr() instead of data() to bring it in

Comment: thanks briansol, you were right. If you want you can create an answer and I will accept it.